# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, echo

```
 echo '<form method="post" autocomplete="on" action='echo htmlspecialcharsb($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);'>
            <input type="text" name="gname" >
            <input type="submit"name="submit" value="search">', $gmeta ? $gmeta : $field['std'], '</form>', '<br />', $field['desc'];
            break;
```

and result this error in line 1 here:

```
autocomplete="on" action='echo htmlspecialcharsb($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);'>
```

Comment: you don't need another `echo` inside, just concatenate `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: ok i do it but still erorr `echo '<form method="post" autocomplete="on" action='htmlspecialcharsb($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);'>` errorcode:`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'htmlspecialcharsb' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' `